# Virtual methods and parameters lookup

Tags: c++, parameters, virtual

I have following classes:

```
Collider (abstract based class)
BoxCollider
MeshCollider
SphereCollider
```

The last 3 inherit from Collider.

The use case is that it should be possible for each collider to check if it collides with any of the other colliders.

I imagine the call should be in the Collider class and look like:

```
void Collider::checkCollisionsWithOtherColliders()
{
for(std::vector<Collider*>::iterator it ....)
{
if(this->isCollidingWith(*it){...}
}
}
```

Now comes the problem how I should define isCollidingWith

I guess I'd need to define it for each pair of colliders, which means each collider type should have a version of this method for each type of collider as argument, e.g. in SphereCollider:

```
class SphereCollider : public Collider
{

bool isCollidingWith(SphereCollider* c){..}
bool isCollidingWith(BoxCollider* c){..}
bool isCollidingWith(MeshCollider* c){..}

};
```

To make sure such methods are accessible thru the Collider base class, I'd need to define

```
class Collider
{
virtual bool isCollidingWith(SphereCollider* c){..}
virtual bool isCollidingWith(BoxCollider* c){..}
.. and so on
};
```

Also, since a call `this->isCollidingWith(*it)` takes just a pointer to Collider and NOT a derived class, I'd wish that the appropriate method of those virtual ones listed is taken automatically in runtime. However, this seems to be not the case: since the parameter is just Collider, it looks for a method with just Collider* parameter.

The only solution I can think of is to define in Collider:

```
bool isCollidingWith(Collider* collider)
{
if (0 != dynamic_cast<SphereCollider*>(collider))
return isCollidingWith(dynamic_cast<SphereCollider*>(collider));
else if (0 != dynamic_cast<BoxCollider*>(collider))
return isCollidingWith(dynamic_cast<BoxCollider*>(collider));
else if ...
}
```

which is not really elegant. Is there any other (proper) way to handle such situations?
Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you will be defining 9 isCollidingWith() methods when there are only 3 types of relationships.

Comment: I'm not sure. Actually a half of the cases will be duplicates and can be optimized out. But it would be interesting to differentiate collisions of box/sphere and box/box

Comment: This is the [Double Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case for [**double dispatch**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch). Won't detail it here since it's an already widely used idiom and even if the wikipedia page become obsolete, a simple google search with the term would yield a good result.

Comment: I would at least note that in C++ this is often accomplished with the visitor pattern.

Comment: @MarkB "The problem described above can be resolved by simulating double dispatch, for example by using a visitor pattern." :)

Comment: lol the first thing I thought of when I saw the word "collider" was "double dispatch". It's *the* classic example.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are inheriting BoxCollider, MeshCollider and SphereCollider from Collider, you do not need to create 3 different methods to accept a parameter of each class. This is why OOP is awesome.

You can use this:

```
class Collider
{
    virtual bool isCollidingWith(Collider* c){..}
};

class SphereCollider : public Collider
{
    bool isCollidingWith(Collider* c){..}
};

class BoxCollider : public Collider
{
    bool isCollidingWith(Collider* c){..}
};

class MeshCollider : public Collider
{
    bool isCollidingWith(Collider* c){..}
};
```

Because the method isCollidingWith is virtual, at runtime, due to polymorphism, the right method will be called based on the object that is calling it ( and provided the inherited class has an implementation for isCollidingWith(Collider *c), else the inherited class will become abstract too).

Example:

```
Collider *c1 = new SphereCollider;
Collider *c2 = new BoxCollider;
Collider *c3 = new MeshCollider;

// To check if Sphere is colliding with anything
// This will go to the implementation in SphereCollider
c1->isCollidingWith(c2);
c1->isCollidingWith(c3);

// To check if Box is colliding with anything
// This will go to the implementation in BoxCollider
c2->isCollidingWith(c1);
c2->isCollidingWith(c3);

// To check if Mesh is colliding with anything
// This will go to the implementation in MeshCollider
c3->isCollidingWith(c1);
c3->isCollidingWith(c2);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not as simple as that. This is a double dispatch problem, something C++ does not handle out of the box. It can be simulated with the visitor pattern, and sometimes you do need to know specifics vs specifics. A dart, for example, will always "collide with" plate armor, but if the shooter is lucky, a small dart can pass right through the holes in chain mail armor.

Comment: Yes, after reading the comments, I realized that. Reading up on double dispatch now :) Thanks for the feedback.